# SQL return max value only

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, max, distinct

I have done some basic queries using max but this one has a little more to it. I am using SSMS 2012. This would also need to include a group or distinct.

Select statement -

```
select A.YEAR1, A.PERIODID 
from GPSTJ..SY40100 A
where A.CLOSED = 0 and A.PERIODID <> 0 and A.series = 5
```

This returns the following results -

```
YEAR1    PERIODID
2015     12
2015     12
2016     1
2016     1
2016     2
2016     2
```

I only want it to return 1 row, with the maximum value in the year column first, and then the maximum Period ID -

```
YEAR1    PERIODID
2016     2
```

Thanks

Comment: Try this ! `select * from (select Year1,Periodid,rn=row_number()over(partition by Year1 order by Periodid desc)  from .... )x where x.rn=1`

Answer (score 5):

Just ordering with `TOP (1)`

```
select TOP (1) A.YEAR1, A.PERIODID 
from GPSTJ..SY40100 A
where A.CLOSED = 0 and A.PERIODID <> 0 and A.series = 5
ORDER BY A.YEAR1 DESC, A.PERIODID DESC
```

Comment: Hi, this one looks nice and simple. Have never used top before but it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `MAX()` so use `SELECT MAX(YEAR1), PERIODID FROM table;`

This will select the highest value in the column.

Comment: You forgot to add `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `having` clause and `group by` year, period ID